# PHP Count how many times code is used on a page

Tags: php, count, include, global

On a page, I have multiple instances of the below code, which grabs snippets of info depending on the ID. If possible, I simply need a way to count exaclty how many times the below code is used on that page. So if I pasted that code 17 times with 17 different IDs, I need a way to generate that total number (17).

I've tried adding things like $count++ to every instance and then getting the total with $count, but that only works if the total is *below* all the instances. But in this case I need the total at the top of the page. Any ideas?

```
<? $rs= mysql_query("select id from Files $order");
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {  
$idnumber = 2696;
require("row.php");
} ?>
```

Comment: Seems like you should have a look at the DRY principle.

Comment: @Chris. While he's doing that he maybe wants to have a look at the MVC principle too.

Comment: *"On a page, I have multiple instances of the below code"* - Why would you want to do that? Now to (hopefully) answer this, both PHP and SQL have a function called `count()` respectively.

Comment: I'm confused as to why the full code in row.php would be necessary? I could easily post it all but I'm simply wanting to count it.

And the reason we need this is a bit complicated. We have SQL setup but in this particular case we're creating a lot of different kinds of pages with this code snippet, and we simply need a total number at the top.

Comment: Then, use SQL's aggregate [`count()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) function. That may very well be what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "page" you mean HTML page, you could just include something like:

```
<div style="display:none" class="count-me"></div>
```

after each closing ?>. Then use jQuery to count the number of times it sees that class and output that somewhere on your page:

```
<script>
     $('#id-of element-where-you-output-number').text( $('.count-me').length );
</script>
```